# Will my CPU get fried if my water cooler fails?

Tags: cpu, cooling, water-cooling

When using a conventional cooler, there is an additional safety net due to radiator's thermal capacity (even if the fan fails). What is not the case for a water cooler. Do I have a risk of getting my CPU fried if the water cooler's pump stops?

Comment: Most 'modern' CPUs have thermal throttling. It'll likely malfunction somewhat, but its unlikely to 'fry'

Comment: The water in the cooler has a greater capacity to store heat than air, and the heat from the CPU would, I expect, set up some modest convection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways a CPU handles heat.

First as said in a comment. Modern CPUs have thermal throttling that will downclock the CPU to try and manage the heat.

Secondly, CPUs also have a last-resort circuit that thermal trips (which will abruptly shut the CPU down) when the temperatures are extremely high and are deemed dangerous enough to cause hardware damage.

Should cooling to the CPU fail it would then first throttle itself down and then if temperatures continue to rise, it will shut itself down.